# Spring autowire automatically in Swing

Tags: java, spring, swing

I add `Rectangle2D` late to the Context. Unfortunately existing beans that list forms, are not updated.

This is the Component to draw on:

```
@Named("area")
public class PaintArea extends JPanel {
  @Inject
  Rectangle2D[] rects; // The formes

  public void paintComponent(...){
    for(Rectangle2D r : rects) {
      g.draw(r);
    }
  }
}
```

This is the function where i add a rectangle:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
  String uniqueName = ....;
  registry.registerBeanDefinition(uniqueName, new AnnotatedBeanDefinition(Rectangle2D.class));
  // This two lines below should work automatically...
  PaintArea o = (PaintArea) context.getBean("area");
  context.getAutowireCapaleBeanFactory().autowireBean(o);

  o.repaint();
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Yes - call new to create that array of Rectangles.  Don't use Spring to inject them.  You want every PaintArea to have its own.  I don't thing Spring is a good choice for Swing UIs.

Comment: "Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`."—[*Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#callbacks).

Comment: @duffymo sounds like an instinct, any conceivable problems?

Comment: Just that there are lots of cases where I don't think DI and Spring are appropriate.  You still call new and instantiate your own instances (e.g. local objects in methods; initializing a private member data structure).  Everything need not be wired by Spring.

Comment: @Peter Rader agree with  duffymo, main proiblem is that PaintArea o = (PaintArea) context.getBean("area"); never is added to already visible container, then all changes are called to invisible "o", your paintComponent() missing super.paintComponent(g), explained here milion times